# pf: difference between 'modulate state' and 'keep state'

Tags: firewall, tcp, macos, pf

What's the difference between "modulate state" and "keep state" in the packet filter (`pf`) firewall?

I'm using MacOS X Catalina 10.15.5. I have no idea how to check what version of `pf` is installed on this machine :\

Comment: macOS shipped with vastly outdated pf. Don't bother, the feature you're looking at is half-working there.

Comment: side-question: how do you check the version of pf that's installed on MacOS? Or any cli command for that matter?

Comment: By indirect evidence mostly… missing features and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packet Filter [originates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PF_(firewall)#History) from OpenBSD:

> The initial version of PF was written by Daniel Hartmeier. It
> appeared in OpenBSD 3.0, which was released on 1 December 2001.

[OpenBSD 3.0](https://www.openbsd.org/30.html):

> A new packet filter, PF, featuring NAT capabilities, with a mostly ipf-compatible syntax.

The [commit about `modulate state`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/commit/b96c47ab9bad4e4e9abee491fbd16bace1162d73) predates this release (2001-08-25). Any MacOS version using PF (which is since OS X 10.6 in [2008](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/net/pf.c.auto.html)) has `modulate state` available.

---

About `modulate state` vs `keep state`, it's all explained in the [OpenBSD's PF FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html).

> *state*
>
> [...]
>
> - `keep state` - works with TCP, UDP, and ICMP. This option is the default for all filter rules.
> - `modulate state` - works only with **TCP**. PF will generate **strong Initial Sequence Numbers** (ISNs) for packets matching this rule.

> The `modulate state` option works just like `keep state`, except that it
> only applies to TCP packets. With modulate state, the Initial Sequence
> Number (ISN) of outgoing connections is randomized. This is useful for
> **protecting connections initiated by certain operating systems that do
> a poor job of choosing ISNs**. To allow simpler rulesets, the modulate
> state option can be used in rules that specify protocols other than
> TCP. In those cases, it is treated as keep state.

So `modulate state` is doing the default `keep state` and *in addition* alters some TCP packets for improved security.

Example:

> ```
> pass out on egress proto { tcp, udp, icmp } from any to any modulate state
> ```

which will "modulate" TCP, and just keep state for others.

---

If you want to know more about TCP innards and TCP ISNs, there are RFCs about it, like:

- [TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)

  > Sequence Number:  32 bits
  >
  > The sequence number of the first data octet in this segment (except
  > when SYN is present). If SYN is present the sequence number is the
  > initial sequence number (ISN) and the first data octet is ISN+1.
- [Defending against Sequence Number Attacks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6528)

  > Unfortunately, the ISN generator described in [RFC0793] makes it
  > trivial for an off-path attacker to predict the ISN that a TCP will
  > use for new connections, thus allowing a variety of attacks against
  > TCP connections [[CPNI-TCP]](http://www.gont.com.ar/papers/tn-03-09-security-assessment-TCP.pdf).